# Reverse Geo Coding

Tags: reverse-geocoding, jxl

We are creating excel file in java using jxl. For Every record based on latitude and longitude we are using reverse geo coding and fetching address of cordinates and then adding into cells. If records are more it takes more time and thus is inefficient, is there any approach we could using reverse geocoding in less time?

Comment: Where does your profiling say the time is being spent? The reverse geocoding itself, creating the Excel cells or somewhere else?

Comment: @PhilipKendall- Yes the reverse geocoding itself. For each record some time it takes 300ms or more, even I have seen for some lat ,long  it even takes more than 1 sec to fetch record.